# My application is not able to access the Excel when I run my .exe from SQL Agent job

Tags: c#, sql, .net, excel, agent

I have an Application that needs to access the Excel. I use Microsoft.Interop dll.

When I execute my .exe directly then it runs good. However when I run the exe through SQL Job (OperatingSystem-CmdExe) then it fails saying with following error

> Executed as user: \SYSTEM. Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 
>   Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'path\Myexcel.xlsx'. 
>   There are several possible reasons:  The file name or path does not exist.  The file is being used by another program. The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.
>   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad)
>   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.ExcelRefresh(String Filename)
>   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args).
>   Process Exit Code 255.  The step failed.

I have checked permissions, path, etc everything. Please help.
SQL Agent is running under my name - and I am System Admin.

Again to emphasise: The exe runs fine when invoked from cmd prompt but fails when invoked via job.

Comment: Do you check the Windows Service "Log On As" on the SQL Agent service ?

Comment: Yes. it is running under my account that has sysadmin access.